# How to decrypt data using private key(.private) in java

Tags: java, openssl, jce

Data is encrypted using OpenSSL in PHP and i would like to decrypt java but getting error in java

**Code for Encryption in PHP-**

```
public function getEncryptedString($cardNumber,$key_id){
              $encryptedCardNumber = '';
              $key_name = "key_{$key_id}"; 
              $pub_key_path =$key_name.".public";  
              $fp=fopen ($pub_key_path,"r"); //Open the public key (key_8.public)
              $pub_key = fread($fp,8192);  //Read public key  key (key_8.public) into 
              fclose($fp); 
               openssl_public_encrypt($cardNumber,$encryptedCardNumber,$pub_key);   
              if($key_id > 4) return rawurlencode(base64_encode($encryptedCardNumber));  
              else return addslashes($encryptedCardNumber);          

    }
```

**Code for Decryption in JAVA-**

```
public static String getDecryptedValue(int keyId,String encryptedCCNumber ,String passPhrase){
              String result="";

              String privateKeyFileName="key_8.private";
              String privateKeyLocation= PropertiesUtil.getProperty("PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY_LOCATION");
             String privateKeyFileNameLocation=privateKeyLocation+privateKeyFileName;
              String decryptedValue= getDecryptedMessage(privateKeyFileNameLocation,encryptedCCNumber,passPhrase);
              return result;

       }


       public static String getDecryptedMessage(String privateKeyFileNameLocation, String encryptedCCNumber,String passPhrase) 
                { 
              byte[] decodedBytesCCNumber= Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedCCNumber.getBytes());
           byte[] decryptedMessage=null; 
           try { 
               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA"); 

                PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(privateKeyFileNameLocation,passPhrase);
               cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey); 
               decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(decodedBytesCCNumber); 

           } catch (Throwable t) { 
              t.printStackTrace();
           }

           System.out.println("new String(decryptedMessage)"+new String(decryptedMessage));
           return new String(decryptedMessage); 

       } 

       private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String privateKeyFileNameLocation,String passPhrase) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
               KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
               ks.load(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFileNameLocation), passPhrase.toCharArray());
               String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
               KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(passPhrase.toCharArray()));
               return keyEntry.getPrivateKey();
           }
```

Java code is giving below error.

```
java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:847)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1221)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are URL-encoding a Base64-encoding of the ciphertext, but you are only deciphering a base64-decoding of it. Either lose the URL-encoding or decode it at the receiver.

Comment: but the error is occuring inside method  while executing                            private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String privateKeyFileNameLocation,String passPhrase)   {ks.load(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFileNameLocation), passPhrase.toCharArray());}

Comment: @user1665785 So in that case your problem is not with decryption as it says in your title, it is with the format of your keyStore file. How did you create it?

Comment: The Private key is generated in server using openssl in pem format.

Comment: Hi EJP ,The Private key is generated in server using openssl in pem format (RSA).So do you mean to say that pem format will not work in java  and to make it work i should convert the key_8.private(PEM format) file in one of the format (PKCS12/PKCS8) .so that java will understand.kinldy let me know how to convert and is it possible to convert it using java code

Comment: @user1665785 Java keystores come in JKS and PKCS12 formats. Check the Javadoc of the keytool.